# How to sign the assertion with Google SAML

Tags: google-apps-script, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace, google-sso

I am trying to setup SAML with GSuite. But I get this error `The Assertion of the Response is not signed and the SP requires it.`

I have configured that the assertion should be signed in my SP. I can see the option to sign the response assertion in other IDP like onelogin, okta. The configuration works fine with other IDP, but cannot see the option to sing the response assertion in GSuite SAML.

In Gsuite I can only see the option to sign the response, but not the assertion.

How can I correctly set this up?

SP metadata looks like this:

````
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#pfxd76b3d5e-171f-a19e-7655-e6cc6664adb0">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>/K0lp4rOuuVcuRlMsx14/t2n0LkkDdJqzyiEa2sar/E=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>xxxx</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>xxxx</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>xxxx</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="xxxx/sso/611b7d0d3783084966599da3/slo"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="xxxx/sso/611b7d0d3783084966599da3/acs" index="1"/>
<md:AttributeConsumingService index="1">
<md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">SP test</md:ServiceName>
<md:ServiceDescription xml:lang="en">Test Service</md:ServiceDescription>
<md:RequestedAttribute Name="" NameFormat="" FriendlyName="" isRequired="false"/>
</md:AttributeConsumingService>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>```
````

Comment: I am having this issue with google as well. please let us know when if you have figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en),

> (Optional) Check the Signed Response box if your service provider requires the entire SAML authentication response to be signed. If this is unchecked (the default), only the assertion within the response is signed.

You may want to uncheck that box to let the default behavior take over.

Comment: "It doesn't work", doesn't work. You'll need to be specific and provide details.